Selecting "A Single App" in Android14 causes createVirtualDisplay() Error
Outlook
Recent security update enable android 14 devices to select "A Single App" with screen capturing. In my android application, when user select "A Single App" and select my application itself on next dialog, createVirtualDisplay() makes Error "Could not create virtual display: xxxx(display name)".
image: Selecting "A Single App"
If possible, I want to know the reason and to fix it.
Code
The error come from this code. (unrelated code is omitted)

class HogehogeActivity : AppCompatActivity(), org.webrtc.VideoCapturer {

    private lateinit var screenCaptureLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>
    
    private var surfaceTextureHelper: SurfaceTextureHelper? = null
    
    override fun onCreate() {
        screenCaptureLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {
            if (it.resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                return@registerForActivityResult
            }
            val data = it.data ?: return@registerForActivityResult
            
            if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) return@registerForActivityResult
            
            val manager = getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE) as? MediaProjectionManager ?: return@registerForActivityResult
            val mediaProjection = manager.getMediaProjection(Activity.RESULT_OK, screenCaptureIntent) ?: return@registerForActivityResult
            
            // Error occur: [DisplayManager] Could not create virtual display: WebRTC_ScreenCapture
            val virtualDisplay = mediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay(
                "WebRTC_ScreenCapture",
                480,
                640,
                400,
                VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_PUBLIC.or(VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_PRESENTATION),
                Surface(surfaceTextureHelper?.surfaceTexture),
                null,
                null
            )
        }
    
        // user tap button to start screen capture.
        binding.button.setOnClickLisner {
            val manager = (activity.getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE) as MediaProjectionManager)
            val screenCaptureIntent = manager.createScreenCaptureIntent()
            screenCaptureLauncher.launch(screenCaptureIntent)
        }
    }
    
    override fun initialize(
        surfaceTextureHelper: SurfaceTextureHelper?,
        applicationContext: Context?,
        capturerObserver: CapturerObserver?
    ) {
        this.surfaceTextureHelper = surfaceTextureHelper
    }

}

I tried

createVirtualDisplay()'s arguments change.
select "A single app" and select other app => createVirtualDisplay() succeeded.
select "Entire screen" => createVirtualDisplay() succeeded.

